# The home page is showing only texts

Tags: 8, media

[image]

I am using the drupal 8.1.2 version but the home page is showing only texts like the image attached. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Sorry but you need to give more info. Clearly your theme is not loading for some reason. As is, the only advice I can give would be to start from scratch and install Drupal again.

Comment: Bare pages like this are almost always an indication of some key stylesheet or other frontend component not loading to render the page. You need to debug what component isn't loading and why.

Comment: try to set correct filesystem that is writable by webserver

Comment: information provided is unclear. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

This sympton indicates that CSS is missing. 
**One reason can be**: It's because that Drupal is not able to crate the aggregated CSS in the files directoy. Give the right permission to the directory (.drupal_root/sites/defaults/files):

In your defaults directory in linux type the following:

```
find files/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
find files/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
```

In windows am not really familiar with it. You will have to search for that.

And after this run a "drush cr" from your console, or try to do that via UI to clear all your caches. Your css will be loaded after this.